# cakephp Fix Url redirection

Tags: cakephp, url-rewriting

OLD                                        ---> NEW

```
http://abc.com/cities/view/1 -->http://abc.com/melbourne-day-tours/

http://abc.com/categories/view/3 -->http://abc.com/melbourne-day-tours/great-ocean-road-tours

http://abc.com/tours/view/1 -->http://abc.com/melbourne-day-tours/great-ocean-road-tours/great-ocean-road-adventure-tour
```

i do have an old project , now i have to do following redirection , what should i do ?
using htaccess ? or any other ways ?

when i put `http://abc.com/melbourne-day-tours/` in my bro, the url in the address bar shd be stay same, and it be call controller and the action for `http://abc.com/cities/view/1` 
thanks

Answer (score 2):

The best way of of doing this is using the CakePHP [Router](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html). You can set routes in `app/Config/routes.php`, for example:

```
Router::connect(
    '/melbourne-day-tours',
    array('controller' => 'cities', 'action' => 'view', 1)
);
```

If you are planning having many routes you might be better of using slugs which are stored in your database. There is some information about that in the link above.

Comment: can i do it with using htaccess in cake ?

Comment: CakePHP already uses htaccess to rewrite URLs so it's not a good idea.

Comment: ya i know but i dont know the specific  controller or action names ! i want Quick job - that this shd be redirect to this !

Comment: I gave you one example, it's not difficult to adapt it for the other URLs. The "old" URLs you posted are all in the same format: `http://example.com/controller/action/id`. You should check the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html) for more info about working with CakePHP.

Answer (score 0):

What i  just done is :

i just  done  is  just putted  lines in `app/webroot/.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^melbourne-day-tours/?$ /cities/view/1 [L]
```

it worked !
 thanks !