# how to redirect with htaccess in cake

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

My Urls are :

```
http://abc.com/cities/view/1 -->http://abc.com/melbourne-day-tours/

http://abc.com/categories/view/3 -->http://abc.com/melbourne-day-tours/great-ocean-road-tours

http://abc.com/tours/view/1 -->http://abc.com/melbourne-day-tours/great-ocean-road-tours/great-ocean-road-adventure-tour
```

when i put `http://abc.com/melbourne-day-tours/` in my bro, the url in the address bar shd be stay same, and it be call controller and the action for `http://abc.com/cities/view/1`

Comment: possible duplicate of [cakephp Fix Url redirection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404912/cakephp-fix-url-redirection)

Answer (score 2):

When you want the URL unchanged in the browser's bar, you must rewrite and *not* redirect

```
RewriteRule ^melbourne-day-tours/?$ /cities/view/1 [L]
```

The other rules look similar.

Comment: +1 , cakephp having 3 htaccess files where shd the code worked ?

Comment: @BhavinRana When you have set the `DocumentRoot` to `/path/to/webroot`, put it in `/path/to/webroot/.htaccess`.

Comment: DocumentRoot to /path/to/webroot  ??

Comment: @BhavinRana I installed CakePHP in my test environment. There's a directory called `.../app/.../webroot`. In Apache's [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost) configuration, I have set the [`DocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot) to this directory.